# Running SBT from an ammonite script

Tags: scala, ammonite

I am trying to write a ammonite script which triggers an SBT task.

So far this is what I have written.

test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env amm
import sys.process._
import java.io.File
import ammonite.ops._, ImplicitWd._

@main
def ini(args: String*) = {
    val server = args.headOption.getOrElse("devserver")
    val path = /'Users/'Foo/'IdeaProjects/'my-project
    val process = Process(Seq("sbt", "clean"), path)
    process.!
}
```

I am having multiple problems here

1. instead of using the `Process` object I want to use the ammnoite `%` to launch the process. But then how do I set the working directory for the process being launched?
2. From the command line I run my code like `sbt "runmain com.test.Foo 1 2 3"`. When calling the process from `%` how can I correctly call runMain with all the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

`%.sbt('runmain,"com.test.foo",arg1,arg2,arg3)(path)`

Where path is the directory you want it performed in & the args are explicitly named, not arg*. It's Scala so you can preset values for arts & you can used named arguments by prefixing the name w/`--'`

Another alternative is to write a shell script to first cd to the directory & then run the ammonite script with parameters.